# Convert int to hexstring in c or obj-c

Tags: c, string, hex

I have a

```
int num = 69;
```

I want a **string** with its hex value "**7E**"

```
char result;
sprintf(&result, %X, num);
```

Seems to work but only gives me the fists char '**7**' how can I get "**7E**"?

Comment: `char result[N];`, where N is something sufficiently large may help. As-is you're invoking *undefined behavior*. (assuming `%X` was supposed to be `"%X"`. Next time post *real code*).

Comment: `7E` hex is `126` in decimal, how did you hope to derive that from integer `69`?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the result is that it has space for one character, not two+null terminator. You need at least three `char`s there.

Here is how you can do it:

```
char buf[9]; // Make the buffer larger to fit bigger numbers
sprintf(buf, "%02X", num);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/AKejdU)

In Objective-C you do it like this:

```
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0X", num];
```

Answer (score 1):

sprintf generates a string.  *result* is a char.  Re-declare it as and drop the &

```
char result[10];  // or something
sprintf(result, "%X", num);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need enough buffer for the hex string since char would give you only 1 character worth of buffer.

```
    int main()
    {
        int num=69;
        char *hex_string = new (char[2]);
        sprintf(hex_string, "%X", num);
        delete(hex_string);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: It is always better to use snprintf to avoid overflows